# What does $\Delta S$ denote in this question?

Tags: geometry

What has been asked to be found in this question?

I don't understand what $\Delta S$ denotes. Please help me regarding this.

[image]

[link to the problem](http://gogeometry.blogspot.in/2008/10/elearn-geometry-problem-195.html)

Comment: Area of $S{{}}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Area of $\Delta ABC$ in terms of in radius and ex-radii?

Comment: Just ignore the $\triangle$. It is a misprint. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle

Comment: @Mick Yes thanks. Now I got it.